# Using setInterval in Internet Explorer - not working? Jquery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, setinterval

I have an upload area on my site that when used within IE9-11 the file path has the C:\fakepath\ preface included on the filename. So I built a workaround to remove this but it is only working in FF and Chrome. When used in IE the fields do not update. I believe it is an issue with the `setInterval` call but I'm not certain. Below is my code. And here is a Fiddle to show the issue (use in IE to replicate issue): http://jsfiddle.net/daQD6/5/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(running, 1);
    function running() {
        var filenameIn = $('input[type=file]').val();
        var filenameOut = filenameIn.split('\\').pop();
        $('#path').text(filenameIn);
        $('#result').text(filenameOut);
    }
});
```

Any ideas on a workaround or cause of issue within IE? Many thanks and happy holidays!

Comment: That's what I thought too but I tried and it still left the fields blank. And above all the console inspection in IE does not show any errors. Thanks for the quick input!

Comment: When defined like that, functions are hoisted, so that isn't the problem. See http://jsfiddle.net/VLBxM/

Comment: Which version of jQuery (if I change to 1.7.2 it seems to work..)

Comment: Sorry, forgot that info. 1.10.1. And yeah, odd that it works with 1.7.2. I think this is what lead me to it being an issue with the `setInterval`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bug in your version of jQuery (v. 1.10.1): http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13980

Use a newer version - v 1.10.2 and higher have the fix.

Comment: Great work. Thank you for the information. Pulled 1.10.2 from the site and retested, working perfectly. I need to remember to check the bugs section more often. Thank you!

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools. You need to acquaint yourself with them to be productive as a javascript developer.

Comment: I agree about the developer tools! But I wasn't locating any errors when using it in IE. I hit F12, operated the upload button while watching the console, but nothing was alerted to me. Am I missing something? I hardly use the tool in IE, mostly FF and Chrome.

Comment: I brought up IE's developer tools since IE had the issue, the script borked on a certain line, I google'd the error, and voila, I found the bug in jQuery and racked up 45 SO points :)

Comment: If you couldn't already tell, I'm pretty new at this so the help is appreciated. Taking your advice I just learned how to move through the script with the developer tool! I see the error **access is denied** issue inside the jQuery file! Thanks again, knowing how to use the tools properly is great. :)

Answer (score 2):

Chris Hardie has already answered your IE issue, but I wanted to bring some things to your attention regarding file input.

I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daQD6/10/) (and changed the jQuery version as per Chris' suggestion) to use the code from [html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/), in their **Using form input for selecting** section.

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>

  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
      output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
                  f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
                  f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
                  '</li>');
    }
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

You'll notice, if you make use of the events associated with the file input, you always get the filename without path in `evt.target.files[0].name`.  If you use the event process, you won't need to `setInterval`.

Comment: Hey thanks, Scott! This is pretty handy, I've bookmarked the links provided (I love the last modified bit). Cheers!